# Where can I find (citable) FTIR spectra of CuCl and CuCl2?

Tags: spectroscopy, reference-request, ir-spectroscopy

I can't seem to find any published/citable infrared (FTIR) spectra in the 4000-400 cm-1 range of CuCl and CuCl2. Does anyone know of a source available, either free or paid?

Answer (score 1):

If your institution holds a subscription to Elsevier's database *Reaxys*, than you may find, based on chemical name, molecular formula, or CAS number (the later for example from a catalogue of a supplier of chemicals) links to primary literature in the section of *spectroscopic properties*. *Reaxys* tries to cover both organic materials (formerly deposited in the Beilstein database) and inorganic / metalorganic materials (formerly deposited in the Gmelin database).  Otherwise, *Scifinder* from the ACS equally points towards primary literatures, too.

Beside the databases behind a paywall, freely accessible databases like the [NIST webbook](http://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/) may be worth to consult; the entry about $\ce{CuCl2}$ [here](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/formula?ID=B1001128&Mask=800)
mentions in the references already one with IR data of gaseous $\ce{CuCl2}$ ([here](http://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1732394)).

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunately I can't access those databases, only paid _articles_. :( The NIST webbook has entries for both, but CuCl (or [ClCu](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?Formula=CuCl&NoIon=on&Units=SI) as they put) has no references in it at all. I checked the article you mention (thanks), but it has no data in the 4000-400 cm-1 range (which is what I need, and I will edit the question now to state it, sorry).